# Adding relying party in ADFS for Sp Initiated SSO using Simplesamlphp

Tags: adfs2.0, simplesamlphp

I am getting error from ADFS 2.0 while adding relying party for simplesamlphp sp federation metadata.

Below is the error image which I am getting while adding rp(relying party).

[image]

I am using Xampp and my virtual host name is simplesamlsp.net as shown in the above image.
 And I installed Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition.
 How to solve the issue to work my simplesamlphp metadata in ADFS 2.0

Answer (score 0):

its most probally because of your firewall or network is blocking it. 
Try downloading the xml-file and add it to adfs manually. 
That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was that, ADFS RP does not recognize the virtual host url.
Importing xml metadata has not solved my problem also.

Then I used a New Machine(Linux Server[Fedora]) and created Self Signed Certificates with that Machine name and it worked for me.

Note: The problem of ADFS 2.0 Management did not solved with the new machine, then I import the xml metadata and tested it, and it worked for me.

Chrome does not validating AD credentials, may be the invalid/unverified certificates issue. As it shows a `Cross sign` on `https://`

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and firefox can have issues with adfs in spesific scenarios.
Have you tried with IE? Do you get the same errors?

You mention cross sign on https:
Did you remember to add the self-signed certificate(s) to the "Trusted Root Certificate"-folder in MMC>Certificates?
Did you change the certificate in IIS and ADFS (if you created new self-signed certificates)?

And about adfs and RP - Did managed to add RP? And is it working?